# Difference between HQL delete query and session.delete()

Tags: java, hibernate, hql-delete

I'm quite new to Hibernate and have a question. What is the difference between deleting an object by using an HQL query and deleting an object by using the `delete(...)` Method of the `Session` Class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Session.delete(...)` is only useful if you already have a reference to the entity you want to delete.

delete-by-query is useful for deleting several objects according to certain criteria, objects that you may not have previously loaded into the session.

I believe that delete-by-query actually loads each entity into the session and deletes them individually - someone correct me if I'm wrong on this.

Comment: But both make the targeted objects transient?

Comment: @Patrick: If those entities have been previously loaded into the session, yes

Comment: Two other Objects have references to the object i want to delete(In collections). Can Hibernate remove those references or do i have to do it by myself?

Comment: It translates the query to native query and executes it. So not loading them I think. An important note is that it doesn't respect cascades

Comment: I was referring to the answer (the final paragraph)

Comment: "I believe that delete-by-query actually loads each entity into the session and deletes them individually " - I think that this is plainly wrong. This would mean that bulk deletions offer no improvement over select + delete in session. I also haven't seen this being mentioned in the hibernate user guide.